# How to check if socket is listening

Tags: go

I need to know if a unix socket (specifically redis socket) is listening using GoLang in an Ubuntu machine. The only way I thought to do this is parsing the

```
netstat --listen
```

command output. Is there any other way?

Comment: Connect your redis client and see what is says. There is also the [ping](https://redis.io/commands/ping) command to test the connectivity.

Comment: There is no other way to check? I may need the solution also to check other sockets

Comment: Try connecting to them over raw TCP using [`net.Dial`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial).

Comment: A socket in itself is meaningless. Just try to connect the appropriate service and it will tell you if it can't.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to [net.Dial](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial), for example:

https://play.golang.org/p/DIsPzOmWqED

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Dial("unix", filepath.Join("/tmp", "my.sock"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("l = %+v\n", l)
}
```

If socket is not "listening" you may get an error like this:

```
2019/08/19 10:20:38 dial unix /tmp/my.sock: connect: connection refused
exit status 1
```